# Best practice to match callable function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to have a set of functions which can be called upon specific input types. I provide a brief example, let's say I have the following description in a JSON

```
{
  "type": "location",
  "precision": 100
}
```

and I have 2 functions such as

```
fun1(type,param) # Here param is intended as the precision
fun2(type,param) # Here param is intended as another variable
```

however, I want to be able to match the description only with `fun1` which has the correct type and param, although the python type of `param` can be the same for both function, however with a different meaning. Moreover, there can be multiple `param` to check.

Has python something handy to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you have already loaded your functions into a dict in Python.

There are many ways to do the job, so I will only write a few of them down here and also only demonstrate only a few.

1. Function decorators to verify, whether the dictionary contains the right variable before calling it. *-- This approach is by my opinion best for short scripts.*
2. If else chain with your types *-- I think, this approach is the best for long term maintenance.*
3. Check in the beginning of function whether you want to run it. *-- If you don't care about anything and want a short code to run in shortest possible time.*
4. Map from type to correct function *-- This approach is for good performance*

#### Demonstration of first approach

First, we have to make a function generating decorators.

```
def dec_gen(the_type: str):

  def dec(func):
    def inner(d: dict):
      if d.get('type') == the_type:
        func(d)

    return inner

  return dec
```

Let's change `fun1` a little bit.

```
@dec_gen('location')
def fun1(d: dict):
  ...your code....
```

#### Demonstration of third approach

Let's change `fun1` a little bit (again)

```
def fun1(d: dict):
  if d.get('type') == 'location':
    ...your code...
```

If you write such header for all `fun1`, `fun2`,..., `funn`, you can just pass the dictionary and it will be run only on few of them.

Of course, this one can get terribly slow for many different types and large `N`, but there is no requirement on speed in your question.

#### Demonstration of fourth approach

See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71239950/2976142).

Comment: I like the first option. Option 2 and 3 are not preferred as I have to write code explicitly inside every function and I can't match them externally without calling them. Same goes for 4.

Comment: @lbedogni Okey. Do you know, how to implement it or do you want a demonstration of it?

Comment: I have a general understanding of decorators but never implemented one myself. Just to clarify: would it be possible to have only one decorator, add the different types in a dictionary, and simply run the decorator to see if that function matches? Otherwise, writing one decorator per function would not be the best and I would use other solutions.

Comment: @lbedogni You must have one decorator per function. But for it, we just write another function generating decorators. :-) -- See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to use a dictionary for the mapping and (optional) associate every function with an appropriate attribute to keep track:

```
# untested

def func1(data, param):
    pass
    # do something

func1.type = "location"

def func2(data, param):
    pass
    # do something

func2.type = "something_else"

funcs = [func1, func2]

type_func_map = {func.type: func for func in funcs}


# apply the function to data:

def apply_matching_func(data, param):
    func = type_func_map.get(data["type"])
    if func:
        return func(data, param)
```

Comment: This seems ok, but it can bulky if I have to check multiple params (which probably wasn't clear from my question)

Comment: depending on your data you can regard multiple parameters as one, e.g. by using a tuple of strings as dictionary key. You just have to make sure that for every possible combination there is some actual value in the dict, or that edge-cases are handled otherwise.